# How to run different profiles using bash or shell script in ubuntu?

Tags: bash, scripts

In windows i just do this.

```
@echo off
for /L %%n in (1,1,10) do start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P user%%n -no-remote imacros://run/?m=we.js ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w 1500 > NUL
```

There is some equivalent in ubuntu to run different profiles the path of my firefox is, `/opt/firefox/firefox` and need make a loop to select the diferent users.

IMPORTANT. I need to run all my profiles at the same time.

The other question is.
Where is the path of my profiles in firefox in ubuntu. In windows is just simple in the appdata but in ubuntu seems more complicated. someone can say me where is the path of my profiles?

Answer (score 2):

I don't grok batch, but guessing at the meaning the bash equivalent would look like:

```
for n in {1..10}
do
    /opt/firefox/firefox -P user$n -no-remote imacros://run/?m=we.js ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w 1500 &> /dev/null &
done
```

- `{n..m}` is the sequence form of [brace expansion in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion). You could also use a C-style for loop:

  ```
  for ((n = 1; n <= 10; n++))
  do
  ...
  done
  ```
- `$n` is how you get the value of variable `n`.
- `&> /dev/null` redirects both error and normal output to the `/dev/null` special device, effectively discarding them
- the `&` by itself sends the command to the background, so the script no longer waits for the command to finish before continuing to the next command.

---

Your Firefox profiles are likely in `~/.mozilla/firefox/`.

---

(Is that `ping` really part of Firefox's arguments?)

Comment: But in the for how will be like in C style? And the extension of file is bash sh or other?

Comment: @SergioRamos like in the second code block `for ((n = 1; n <= 10; n++))`, the rest of the code remains the same. The extension is up to you: https://askubuntu.com/q/803434/760903

Comment: I just have one small problem when i run the script only open one profile (doesnt open all at the same time).  once time i close the first profile of my firefox open the second profile, i mean that not open all profiles in once time. Its not possible to open all at the same time?

Comment: You may need to *background* each instance, by adding `&` to the end of the command (otherwise the shell loop will wait for each instance to close before continuing).

Comment: @sergio yes, it's possible. See steeldriver's comment and my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

The default Unix shell does not give you a one to one equivalent for all the features you're using. Here are what you can do with the basic shell:

#### Trace

```
@echo off
```

By default a shell script is silent, so it is "off" by default. The flag to turn on trace is `-x` (`set -x`).

#### Loop 1 to 10

```
for /L %%n in (1,1,10)
```

This can be done in a Unix shell script using a variable and a `while`. Newer shells, such as `bash`, offer ways to write such, but if you want to write a script that works on (nearly) all Unix machines, then you want to stick to the basic features:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=1
while test $n -le 10
do
  ...
  n=`expr $n + 1`
done
```

The `...` is the script to be executed 10 times. The `expr` command is used to increment the counter by one on each iteration. Notice the spaces, they are important (not the indentation, although I would suggest you keep the indentation proper).

As @Olorin mentioned, the `expr` command can also be replaced by:

```
n=$(($n + 1))
```

#### Start Firefox as a background process

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" &
                    -P user%%n -no-remote imacros://run/?m=we.js
```

(I broke the line, in DOS script that requires an `&` at the end of the line).

Here you start a program using "start" which means it goes in the background. And you specify parameters, one of which uses that counter `n`. Assuming firefox is in your path (it will if you installed the default version) then you do not need a full path, just the following:

```
firefox -P user$n -no-remote imacros://run/?m=we.js &
```

This is an `sh` script where the ending `&` is used to start that process in the background. That means the command is started and the shell returns immediately.

You also have a special variable set that gives you the PID of the new process. This could be useful later if you want to send a signal or just know whether the process is still running or not. (i.e. `FIREFOX_PID=$!`--in your case, though, you're going to start 10 of them... just one such variable would not work for you.)

#### Send one quiet ping with a 1.5s timeout

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -n 1 -w 1500 > NUL
```

This ping looks like a separate line of code. The `-n 1` is to repeat one time and the `-w 1500` to specify the timeout. The `-w` is one to one equivalent on Linux. The `-n` (number), however, has to be replace by `-c` (count). Finally, the `NUL` special file can be replaced by `/dev/null`.

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -c 1 -w 1500 > /dev/null
```

Note: to make ping quiet, you can also use `-q` as in:

```
ping 192.168.1.1 -q -c 1 -w 1500
```

Of course, if the `ping` is part of the Firefox command line (unlikely) then you probably shouldn't transform it at all.

Comment: Even sticking to the basic features, its probably cleaner to use `$(( ... ))` than `expr`.