# File extensions are hidden in ubuntu 18.04 Bionic

Tags: python, nautilus, files, filesystem, filemanager

When typing in this command:

```
touch ./__init__.py
```

This is what the file looks like in nautilus > right click `__init__.py`:

[image]

as you can see, its a text file instead of a py file.

I am using ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

How can I enable file extensions in the terminal?

Comment: Related: [Do file-extensions have any purpose (for the operating system)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803434/do-file-extensions-have-any-purpose-for-the-operating-system)

Answer (score 2):

In Linux / Ubuntu, file extension really are only used for the user to easily identify what the file is.

Using the command `file` can show you what the file is actually supposed to be.  It will read the contents of the file and tell you what it is.  So, when a file is empty, it just shows a normal text icon. Once it has content then it will show correctly.

Examples:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/tmp$ touch file.bsh
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/tmp$ file file.bsh 
file.bsh: empty
```

[image]

[image]

Added `#!/bin/bash` to the file.bsh file:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/tmp$ cat file.bsh 
#!/bin/bash
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~/tmp$ file file.bsh 
file.bsh: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

[image]

[image]