# Why do files created by Mousepad or Leafpad not have extensions by default?

Tags: filename

Normally, every text document has an extension. With LibreOffice Writer, the extension could be `.odt` or `.doc`, etc depending on your preference but mousepad and leafpad don't provide extensions automatically. I do not mind that, but I do not understand why those files do not have an extension. Why is that?

Comment: You write "Normally, every text document has an extension" but that isn't strictly true. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267250/61798

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/803434/do-file-extensions-have-any-purpose-for-the-operating-system

Comment: Normally in Windows, but there are many examples of files without any extension in Linux.

Answer (score 3):

With LibreOffice Writer you are creating an Open Document (word document) file, so by default it suggests odt extension because it knows what the file is supposed to be.

With leafpad, ,mousepad, gedit, and any other text editors the options are endlessness.

The file can be a simple text file or anything else. it can be a PHP, Perl or Python script, it can be an HTML or XML markup language, JSON file, config file or anything else that you can think of.

So it doesn't use any extension by default. That is up to you to choose the one which best suits you.