# How to differentiate between a file without an extension and a folder without using `cd`?

Tags: command-line, bash, files, directory

What is the difference between a file without an extension and a folder? What I mean exactly is that when I create a file in the terminal, for example:

```
touch somefile
```

then delete that file and create a directory with the same name:

```
mkdir somefile
```

they look the same in `ls`. How to differentiate between them without using `cd somefile`?

Also, I don't know how files without extensions work in Linux. I couldn't find an article on the internet, so I wish you can help me with it.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way is to use the `file` command, which is generally used to determine a file's type (see [`man file`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/file.1.html)). So, if you run:

```
file somefile
```

and the output is:

```
somefile: directory
```

then `somefile` is obviously a directory.

If `somefile` is not a directory, then you'll get an output depending on the file's type. For example, if `somefile` was a PNG image, you would get information about it similar to the following:

```
somefile: PNG image data, 730 x 518, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Files on Linux do not necessarily have an extension. Quoting from [Byte Commander's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/803451/618353) in the question [Do file-extensions have any purpose (for the operating system)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803434/do-file-extensions-have-any-purpose-for-the-operating-system) :

> *Usually* Linux does not rely on file names (and file extensions i.e. the part of the file name after the normally last period) and instead determines the file type by examining the first few bytes of its content and comparing that to a list of known [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Answer (score 5):

You can run

```
ls -l
```

Directories will have `d` in the permissions, like

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

Also in Ubuntu directories are blue.

Answer (score 5):

Let's test this by creating a file (`test`) and a directory (`testfile`):

```
me:~$ touch test
me:~$ mkdir testfile
```

**If you are using a color terminal**, you can see the difference using plain old `ls`. Directories are a different color:

```
me:~$ ls
test  testfile   # Oops, we said color!
```

[image]

**If you are using a monochrome terminal**, use the `-l` flag. You can see the difference in the first column of output:

```
me:~$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me    0 Aug 14 11:49 test
drwxrwxr-x 2 me me 4096 Aug 14 11:49 testfile
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `bash`'s tests:

```
obj=fileordir
[[ -d $obj ]] && echo "directory"
[[ -f $obj ]] && echo "file"
```

Read `man bash`

Answer (score 1):

Use the -F flag:

```
ls -F
```

This will show a slash for directories:

```
mydirectory/
myfile
```