# I Can't Compile C++ Program

Tags: c++

When I run the command `gcc CCC.Cpp` I get this error:

> CCC.Cpp: file not recognized: file format not recognized
> Collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

This is the content of `CCC.Cpp` file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){cout << "CCC";return 0;}
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of command output. Copy the text here and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code. Also add the output of `cat -A CCC.Cpp`.

Comment: Please install the C++ compiler : `sudo apt install g++` ..... and use g++ for C++ code. ...... ...... https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text

Comment: Rename your file to `CCC.cpp` and use the command `g++` instead.

Comment: Related: [Compiling C source file without .c suffix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380558/compiling-c-source-file-without-c-suffix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename the file from *CCC.Cpp* to *CCC.cpp* first and then compile your application by G++ (C++ compiler).

Reproducible way:

```
sudo apt-get install g++

mv CCC.Cpp CCC.cpp
g++ CCC.cpp -o CCC
./CCC
```

Also you should not use *root* account for daily non-administrative task.

Comment: After installing `g++` and renaming the source file, you can use just `make CCC` instead of the `g++ ...` command.